# Plotly-Dash: How to improve plot responsiveness to slider changes

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm developing a tool to visualize the effects of a set of parameters on a mathematical function by modifying those parameters via Dash sliders. I'm using the approach from a few of the Dash tutorial examples which use a callback to replace the figure.

This works, but the plot isn't as responsive to slider changes as built-in operations such as rotating the plot via dragging. This is especially the case when there are many elements in the figure.

**Is there a different approach that will improve responsiveness? For example, is there a way to target only the plot elements that changed rather than replacing the entire figure?**

Here's a minimal working example consisting of a static circle (with many samples) and a line segment that we rotate via a slider. Rotation of the line segment is quite choppy.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import numpy as np

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# plot a circle
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10000)  # intentionally use many points to exaggerate the issue
x = np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(t)
z = np.zeros_like(t)
marker_size = 4
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='lines'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
    x=[0.0, 0.0], y=[0.0, 0.0], z=[0.0, 0.0],
    marker=go.scatter3d.Marker(size=marker_size),
    line=dict(width=3.0),
    showlegend=False,
))

fig.update_layout(
    uirevision='constant',
    autosize=False,
    width=900,
    height=900,
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(range=[-1, 1]),
        yaxis=dict(range=[-1, 1]),
        zaxis=dict(range=[-1, 1.0]),
        aspectratio=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2),
    ),
)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    ),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Slider(
                id='slider-phi',
                min=0.0,
                max=360.0,
                step=1.0,
                value=0.0,
                marks={0: '0', 180: '180', 360: '360'},
                updatemode='drag',
            ),
        ],
        style=dict(width='50%'),
    ),
    html.Div(children='', id='output-box'),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('example-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('slider-phi', 'value')],
    [State('example-graph', 'figure')]
)
def display_structure(phi, myfig):
    myfig['data'][1]['x'][1] = np.cos(np.radians(phi))
    myfig['data'][1]['y'][1] = np.sin(np.radians(phi))
    myfig['data'][1]['z'][1] = 0

    return myfig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I think the reason for this situation is due to the large amount of computation required to draw in real time. I checked the operation by halving the size of the graph and using a step value of 10. Dragging the slider will also be followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of responsiveness can be attributed to two key factors. The first is, as you note, that the whole figure is updated each time rather than just the desired trace. You can avoid this by targeting the `extendData` property instead of the `figure` property,

```
@app.callback(Output('example-graph', 'extendData'), [Input('slider-phi', 'value')])
def update_data(phi):
    # tuple is (dict of new data, target trace index, number of points to keep)
    return dict(x=[[0, np.cos(np.radians(phi))]], y=[[0, np.sin(np.radians(phi))]]), [1], 2
```

The second factor is that the callback is executed server side rather than client side, i.e. requests are exchange between client and server each time you move the slider. To avoid this, you can move the update to the client by converting the callback to a [clientside callback](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks),

```
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(phi) {
        // tuple is (dict of new data, target trace index, number of points to keep)
        return [{x: [[0, Math.cos(phi/180*Math.PI)]], y:[[0, Math.sin(phi/180*Math.PI)]]}, [1], 2]
    }
    """, Output('example-graph', 'extendData'), [Input('slider-phi', 'value')]
)
```

which should yield reasonable responsiveness. Here is how it looks on my laptop,

[image: Responsiveness]

For completeness, here is the full code,

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import numpy as np

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# plot a circle
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10000)  # intentionally use many points to exaggerate the issue
x = np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(t)
z = np.zeros_like(t)
marker_size = 4
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='lines'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
    x=[0.0, 0.0], y=[0.0, 0.0], z=[0.0, 0.0],
    marker=go.scatter3d.Marker(size=marker_size),
    line=dict(width=3.0),
    showlegend=False,
))

fig.update_layout(
    uirevision='constant',
    autosize=False,
    width=900,
    height=900,
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(range=[-1, 1]),
        yaxis=dict(range=[-1, 1]),
        zaxis=dict(range=[-1, 1.0]),
        aspectratio=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2),
    ),
)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    ),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Slider(
                id='slider-phi',
                min=0.0,
                max=360.0,
                step=1.0,
                value=0.0,
                marks={0: '0', 180: '180', 360: '360'},
                updatemode='drag',
            ),
        ],
        style=dict(width='50%'),
    ),
    html.Div(children='', id='output-box'),
])

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(phi) {
        // tuple is (dict of new data, target trace index, number of points to keep)
        return [{x: [[0, Math.cos(phi/180*Math.PI)]], y:[[0, Math.sin(phi/180*Math.PI)]]}, [1], 2]
    }
    """, Output('example-graph', 'extendData'), [Input('slider-phi', 'value')]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can a similar approach be used for less trivial cases where the new data cannot be calculated via javascript? Perhaps by pre-computing the output for the entire parameter range server-side, then sending a ``lookup table'' which can be accessed via a client-side callback?

Comment: Yes, in that case you could send the data to the client using a normal callback targeting e.g. a `Store` component, and then use the clientside callback to update the graph.

Comment: Can this approach be adapted for multiple sliders corresponding to different parameters, potentially for curves in different traces? It appears  Dash only allows one callback per output, so each slider would need to use the same callback. I'm not sure how to determine which slider triggered the callback and therefore which data needs to be updated.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. While you can only assign one callback per output, you can add as many inputs (in your case, sliders) to a callback as you like. You can determine what input triggered the callback via the [`callback_context`][1]. It's a bit off topic to the original question though, so an extended discussion might be better suited for another question.

  [1]: https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks

Comment: I've opened a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895124/plotly-dash-how-to-determine-trigger-input-in-client-side-callback) to discuss handling of multiple trigger inputs in the same client-side callback.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like although `display_structure` modifies `myfig` in place, the return value is taken as a brand new plot which plotly will render all over again.

Is there any chance that the callback does not require a return value? If your function modifies the plot attributes this could be in place.

FYI: I use `bokeh` and have limited knowledge about `plotly`.

Comment: Thanks. This was my first thought too. I tried changing the output to a dummy element (e.g., assigning text to a `div`), but then the plot did not update at all.