# Plotly-Dash: How to determine trigger input in client-side callback

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, plotly-dash

Dash's documentation describes how to determine which input triggered a callback in the case of server-side callbacks: [Advanced Callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks).

**Is there a way to determine which input triggered a *client-side* callback?**

It looks like this functionality was added in version 1.13.0 ([#1240](https://github.com/plotly/dash/pull/1240)), but my browser console indicates that `dash_clientside.callback_context` is `undefined`. I am running Dash version 1.19.0.

**Edit:
The error I was experiencing was due to an issue with my Dash installation. I had installed via `conda install dash`, and it appears the Dash packages on the Anaconda main channel have issues. Installing from conda forge fixed the problem: `conda install -c conda-forge dash`. See accepted answer for a working example.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. As you note yourself, the information is available in the `dash_clientside.callback_context` variable. Here is a small example,

```
import dash_html_components as html
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

# Create app.
app = Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button("Button 1", id="btn1"), html.Button("Button 2", id="btn2"), html.Div(id="log")
])
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(x, y){
        const triggered = dash_clientside.callback_context.triggered.map(t => t.prop_id);
        return "Hello from [" + triggered + "]";
    }
    """, Output("log", "children"), [Input("btn1", "n_clicks"), Input("btn2", "n_clicks")])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

tested with `dash==1.18.1` on python 3.8 on Linux Mint 20.

Comment: The problem turned out to be an issue with my Dash installation in Anaconda. Installing from conda forge instead of the main channel fixed the problem. Thanks for the working example -- it was helpful for debugging!